# How do you show different table data when button is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

i'm trying to show different table data when a button is triggered using javascript/angularjs. I've given a unique ID for each table and I would to show specific table when the `"next"` button is triggered.

I am now currently using `.show()` and `.hide()` function which only allows me to show only 2 table data. Does anyone have any methods such as looping? Thanks!

In my javaScript file:

```
 <button type="button" id="nextbtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addDataTable1(), addDataTable2(), addDataTable3()">Next</button>
```

In my script tag:

```
 function next(){
   $(".table1Data").hide();
   $(".table2Data").show();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an event handler for your button's onclick event?

Comment: yes, i've added

Comment: Can you share that code so we can help you fix what's not working?

Comment: I've rephrase my question hope its more understandable.

Comment: Can you please share the code you're working with? That'll make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Could you please include the JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class `table`, or whatever you prefer to name it, a `toggle()` method, and show/hide css classes you could do something like this:

```js
function toggle() {
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll('.table');

  for (var i in tables) {
    if (tables[i].classList.contains('show')) {
      tables[i].classList.add('hide');
      tables[i].classList.remove('show');
    } else {
      tables[i].classList.add('show');
      tables[i].classList.remove('hide');
    }
  }
}
```

That'll let you loop over all of your tables and toggle them on or off based on their class. If it is being shown, has the `.show` class, then you hide it with `.hide` and vice versa.

---

Same example with `.hide()` and `.show()`

```js
function toggle() {
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll('.table');

  for (var i in tables) {
    if (tables[i].classList.contains('show')) {
      tables[i].hide();
    } else {
      tables[i].show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but the contains part doesn't really work for me as not all table contains show. check out my updated concerns on my post. Grateful for you help !